# Not receiving information from function

Tags: python

I started on a tcp chat program for the terminal and finally got a gui designed. Here is a function from the gui file:

```
 def on_connect_clicked(self):
    x = 1
    print x
    return x
```

or I tried with self:

```
 def on_connect_clicked(self):
    self.x = 1
    print self.x
    return self.x
```

In my second file

```
 class main(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
     Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
     QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
     self.setupUi(self)
     self.ip = self.lineEdit.text()
     self.port = self.lineEdit_2.text()





s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = main()
    myapp.show()
    print main().x
    if main().x == 1:
        try :
            s.connect((main.ip, main.port))
            print 'connected'
            main().x = 0
        except :
            print 'Unable to connect'
            main().x = 0


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But the problem is that it is setting x to 1 but its not seeing that and it doesnt do anything inside of the if. How can I solve this?

Comment: no i have not, that doesnt answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont create new instances of main each time. use the current one you already have

```
myapp.show()
print myapp.x
if myapp.x == 1:
    try :
        s.connect((myapp.ip, myapp.port))
        print 'connected'
        myapp.x = 0
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        myapp.x = 0
```

Comment: @AaronGill-Braun so now you need to debug it. step over each statement and see whats messing up / not working

Comment: do you have an ide that you can execute this script in? if not then yea you would need to print statements everywhere

Comment: do you know how to use it? set a breakmark on multiple lines and debug the file

Comment: @AaronGill-Braun what did you turn up?

Comment: nothing, it just hit the if statement one but every time i hit the button, it wouldnt work

Comment: thats probably because this is in the __main__ part. you may want to move some of this logic to another part of your code